# Jquery - find / each triggered twice

Tags: jquery, find, iteration, each

I have the following code :

```
var jqxhr = $.get(url, function(downloadedPage) {
     //alert("success");
})

.done(function(downloadedPage) {
        var newRows = $(downloadedPage).find("table.articles tbody");
        var rowsToAdd = [];

        alert (newRows.html().split("<tr>").length); // gives 733
        $("BODY").after("<code>" + escapeHtml(newRows.html()) + "</code>"); // prints a list of <tr></tr> : 733 lines

        newRows.find("tr").each(function(index) {
            alert(index); // goes up to 1464
            var row = $(this);

            rowsToAdd.push("<tr>" + row.html() + "</tr>");
        });

        alert(rowsToAdd.length); // gives 1464
```

I don't understand why this code inserts me twice the number of lines in rowsToAdd... Why using a  733 lines container, it iterates "near" twice the number of lines into it (733 vs 1464).

If I replace the first call :

```
$(downloadedPage).find("table.articles tbody");
```

with

```
$(downloadedPage).find("table.articles:first tbody");
```

then the problem is gone.

Can someone explain me what is wrong there ?

Comment: Well add some of your html aswell. You probably have 2 elements matching the "table.articles tbody" selector on your html

Comment: @MKougiouris OK, that's the case, but even with that, I don't understand why using a 733 lines container, it iterates "near" twice the number of lines into it (733 vs 1464).

Comment: well... add the html as well. We are doing programming you know, not black magic :P I guess it could be just some newline character artifact maybe, its hard to tell without looking anything. Ill make an answer off the comment, i do love me some rep just like the next guy :D

Answer (score -1):

You are having more elements selected by your selector.
if `:first` fixes your problem, that means that there must be more elements getting selected without it, so the selection is wrong.

For the reason of the difference on the container you could add your html or make a fiddle out of it so we can inspect it better